# Circular template argument list between circular dependency class members producer/consumer

Tags: c++, templates

I have a circular dependency between two templated classes.

`Aggregator` contains a class member of template parameter type `DATA_LISTENER`. However, `DATA_LISTENER` needs to contain a reference to `Aggregator` to return data. This means I cannot define the template for each because they both require the other.

What's the best solution? `Listener1` needs to be passed inside `Aggregator` because I have multiple data sources and they need to be aggregated here, but `Aggregator` needs to be generic to accept different `DATA_LISTENER`s.

```
int main()
{
    Aggregator<int, double, Listener1<Aggregator....????>> my_obj;  // Problem: cannot define Aggregator without Listener1
}

template<class NA, class ABC, class DATA_LISTENER>
struct Aggregator
{
   Aggregator() : _sd(*this){}

   void receiveData(int f)
   {
        std::cout << "Received data from SD" << std::endl;
   }

   DATA_LISTENER<Aggregator<NA, ABC, ?????>> _sd;    // Problem cannot define DATA_LISTENER without Aggregator
   NA _na;
   ABC _abc;
};

template<class DESTINATION>
struct Listener1
{
    Listener1(DEST& destination) : _destination(destination){}

    void receiveData(int f)
    {
        _dest.receiveData(f);
    }

    DESTINATION& _destination;
};
```

Comment: Can `Aggregator` take a `template template` argument? As in pass in `template<typename...> class Listener`, and then expand `Listener<Aggregator>` inside of `Aggregator`?

Comment: @Human-Compiler Not sure I completely understand. You mentioned `Listener<Aggregator>`, did you mean `DATA_LISTENER<Aggregator>`?

Comment: *"However, `DATA_LISTENER` needs to contain a reference to `Aggregator` to return data."* -- [why](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The third template parameter to `Aggregator` should be a template parameter, and not a type parameter. Making it a template parameter results in everything else falling into place.

```
template<class NA, class ABC, template<typename> class DATA_LISTENER>
struct Aggregator
{
   Aggregator() : _sd(*this){}

   void receiveData(int f)
   {
   }

   DATA_LISTENER<Aggregator> _sd;
   NA _na;
   ABC _abc;
};

template<class DESTINATION>
struct Listener1
{
    Listener1(DESTINATION& destination) : _destination(destination){}

    void receiveData(int f)
    {
        _destination.receiveData(f);
    }

    DESTINATION& _destination;
};



int main()
{
    Aggregator<int, double, Listener1> my_obj;
}
```

[Live link](https://godbolt.org/z/zsY6f5nPW)